# Regex doesn't detect symbol

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

User input might look like:

- `*` symbol with 1 character limit (no other symbols than `*`)

or

- A-E, a-e letters with 1 character limit

Following data is valid examples: *; a; A; e; D

I don't understand why `^[A-Ea-e]{1}\*?$` doesn't work?

https://regex101.com/r/iG7wG6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a character class:

```
^[A-Ea-e*]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG7wG6/2)

You regex is only allowing an optional `*` after `A-E` or `a-e` but never `*` alone.

Comment: It works great. What if second condition with 3 character limit and first 1 character?

Comment: like this? ^[A-Ea-e]{3}\*?$

Comment: In that case it will be `^([A-Ea-e]{3}|\*)$`

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex groups:

```
^([A-Ea-e]|\*)$
```

You want to have two different alternatives:

1. one of the A-E or a-e characters, OR
2. the * character.